# How to handle spaces in path names in for loop?

Tags: batch-file

Trying to use the path to the current script, and the path contains spaces in it. I can't seem to get it to work though:

```
C:\Test Directory>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7486-CEE6

 Directory of C:\Test Directory

08/31/2010  07:28 PM    <DIR>          .
08/31/2010  07:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/31/2010  07:28 PM                20 echoit.cmd
08/31/2010  07:28 PM                94 test.cmd
               2 File(s)            114 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  344,141,197,312 bytes free

C:\Test Directory>type echoit.cmd
@echo off
echo %*

C:\Test Directory>type test.cmd
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%~dp0\echoit.cmd Hello World') do (
    echo %%a
)

C:\Test Directory>test
'C:\Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Test Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `test.cmd` to the following:

```
   @echo off

   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('"%~dp0\echoit.cmd" Hello World') do (
    echo %%a
   )
```

You need to set the entire command, minus arguments, in quotes.  The Windows command prompt treats a collection of words as a single command when the entire collection is quoted, that is why you must exclude the `Hello World` arguments.  If you were to include that in the quotes, Windows would treat that as part of the command not as arguments.

Comment: great, now get it to work for 'c:\program files (x86)\' instead of 'c:\Test Directory'

Comment: It should work for 'C:\Program Files (x86)' in the same way.  What are you seeing?

Comment: I did not have tokens=* after adding that and including "" quotes around usage it fixed my spacing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding quotes?

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('"%~dp0\echoit.cmd" Hello World') do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using ~fs0, ie

```
C:\Test Directory>type test.cmd
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%~fs0\echoit.cmd Hello World') do (
 echo %%a
)
```

where %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only