# Path with spaces in for loop of a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying this command:

```
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%i in (`"%~dp0imagex.exe" /info "%~dp0DVD\sources\install.wim" ^| findstr /c:"Image Count:"`) do set ImageCount=%%i 
echo %ImageCount%
```

I get error if the path %~dp0 contains spaces like "D:\my work". Although I used usebackq and back quote instead of single quote.

the error message is:'D:\my' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the wrong in my command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[batch - How to handle spaces in path names in for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614658/how-to-handle-spaces-in-path-names-in-for-loop)".

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code that would generate the error you are reporting. USEBACKQ should not be needed, but it can't hurt. Are you sure the above is the exact command in your script?

Comment: Try running it with `echo on` instead of `off` to see if you can spot any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this doesn't work:

```
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%i in (`"%~dp0imagex.exe" /info "%~dp0DVD\sources\install.wim" ^| findstr /c:"Image Count:"`) do set ImageCount=%%i 
echo %ImageCount%
```

---

Try this:

```
pushd %~dp0
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%i in (`imagex.exe" /info "DVD\sources\install.wim" ^| findstr /c:"Image Count:"`) do set ImageCount=%%i 
echo %ImageCount%
popd
```

Comment: The missing `~` was inadvertantly dropped in my previous edit of the question - I have restored it to the question. `%~dp0` already has a trailing \ - you do not need to add another one. Adding an additional one will not hurt unless the script is running from the root directory.

Comment: @dbenham Hmm. I never noticed that.

Comment: @tcc Added a different suggestion.