# Batch File: For Loop: Opens file instead of Rading it. Why?

Tags: batch-file

The code below works when the file name (i.e. links.txt) only is specified without quotes (might work with quotes, but I haven't tested it.).

When I substitute the filename for an entire file path, which also includes spaces, the batch file doesn't work the way it should. Instead, the text file is opened and when I close the text file, the cmd box then shows the message of Echo is off. It's like on the first instance of the loop it's opening the file. Why is this happening?

```
@echo off

SET var=
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f %%i in ('"Z:\My Docs\links.txt"') DO (
   SET var=!var!%%i 
)
echo !var!


ENDLOCAL



pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("Z:\My Docs\links.txt") do ...
```

If you use single quotes around your file name, `for` command interprets you want to execute it, but with only double quotes, it is considered as a literal string.

From the `for` help on `usebackq` (see `for /?`): `... allows the use of double quotes to quote file names in file-set`

Comment: Thank you. I put the single quotes because that's what I understood from others posts one had to do for paths that contain spaces: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263458/path-with-spaces-in-for-loop-of-a-batch-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263458/path-with-spaces-in-for-loop-of-a-batch-file) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614658/how-to-handle-spaces-in-path-names-in-for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614658/how-to-handle-spaces-in-path-names-in-for-loop).

Comment: If I leave the links.txt file in the path mentioned above, but put the bat file in `Z:\My Docs\BatFiles`, how can I reference the text file? How do I tell the code to read from one level up. I see posts mentioning `%dp0`, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this case.